# this.userId not displaying user

Tags: meteor

I'm publishing users and a second collection called joboffers. The joboffers collection stores the userIds for employer and candidate. I would like to get the candidate name to display next to the joboffer, for an admin page, however nothing I do seems to work. All of the joboffers display but not the candidate name. In my console I just get **object** .

Path: `publish.js`

```
// publish all jobs for admin to view
Meteor.publish('allJobs', function () {
  return JobOffers.find({});
});

Meteor.publish('allUsersWithJobs', function () {
  var offers = JobOffers.find({}, {fields: {candidateUserId: 1}}).fetch();
  var ids = _.pluck(offers, 'candidateUserId');

  options = { fields: {username: 1, emails: 1, "profile.firstName": 1, "profile.familyName": 1 } };
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $in: ids } }, options);     
});
```

Path: `alljoboffers.js`

```
Template.alljoboffers.onCreated(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe("allJobs");
  Meteor.subscribe("allUsersWithJobs");

});

    Template.alljoboffers.helpers({
        alljoboffers: function() { 
            return JobOffers.find({});
        },
        candidateName: function() {     
            console.log(this);

            var user = this.userId;
            var candidate = (user && user.profile && user.profile.firstName);

            return candidate;
        },
    });
```

Path: `alljoboffers.html`

```
{{#each alljoboffers}}
    {{positionTitle}}

    {{#with candidateName}}
        {{profile.firstName}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing user id and user object. It's a good idea to create a global helper to help keep a convention on how you manage them. This will help reduce the confusion. For example:

```
Template.registerHelper('usernameById', function(userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
  return user && user.profile.firstName;
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each alljoboffers}}
  {{positionTitle}}
  {{usernameById candidateUserId}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hubert. I didn't realise that at all and I appreciate the suggestion about creating a global helper. I wish I had done that at the beginning of the project. Thanks again!